# Programmatically activate User-Defined Cost Allocation Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

### Background

I've just created some new tags in my AWS tenant using their [Amazon Resource Groups Tagging API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).

### Problem

There doesn't seem to be anyway of activating the newly created tags programmatically. So I still need to log into my account and manually click a button or two.

This seems like a glaringly obvious shortcoming.

### Question

Has anyone else come up against this and found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS CLI now have it. See [update/activate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/update-cost-allocation-tags-status.html) and [list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/list-cost-allocation-tags.html) actions

Example:

```
TAGKEY='aws:createdBy'
aws ce update-cost-allocation-tags-status --cost-allocation-tags-status="TagKey=${TAGKEY},Status=Active"
```